# Flutter: check if device supports eSim

Tags: flutter

Is there any possibility to check if a device supports eSim on Flutter?

I know it can be done with Flutter Platform Channels but I am particularly interested in Flutter solution.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?